# Copying file one location to another

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi

below is mentioned code in shell script

```
SOURCE="/my/folder"
DESTINATION="/my/destination"

cp -r "$SOURCE/subdir/"* "$DESTINATION/another_sub/"
```

code is giving me an error

```
/my/folder: no such a file or directory
```

what is wrong with this code. I checked for folders also if I put directly on the terminal it is working but using shell script it is not working

Comment: do `ls -l /my/folder` what is the output

Comment: put that ls in the script. And try with echo in front of the cp command to see how it is expanded, if you try to go to "/my/folder" with the " " that would fail...

Answer (score 1):

```
/my/folder: no such a file or directory
```

This error indicates that it can't find that folder from root `/`.

Try

```
SOURCE="./my/folder"
DESTINATION="./my/destination"
```

if the script is run in the same directory as the folders. Or use

```
SOURCE="~/my/folder"
DESTINATION="~/my/destination"
```

if the folders are located off your user's home folder.

Answer (score -1):

**How to Copy a file from one Source location to another  Destination location in Linux Operating System.**

Follow below code & command as per your ***Source*** to the ***Destination*** location.

```
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ ls
copy.sh  destination_dir  source_dir
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ tree
.
├── copy.sh
├── destination_dir
└── source_dir
    └── source_file.txt

2 directories, 2 files
```

```
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ cat copy.sh

#!/bin/bash
source_location='/home/ubuntu/copyfile/source_dir/source_file.txt'
Destination_location='/home/ubuntu/copyfile/destination_dir'
`cp -r $source_location $Destination_location`

ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ sh copy.sh
```

```
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ tree
.
├── copy.sh
├── destination_dir
│   └── source_file.txt
└── source_dir
    └── source_file.txt

2 directories, 3 files
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$
```

[image]

```
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ mkdir source_dir
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ mkdir destination_dir
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ ls
destination_dir  source_dir
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ cat > source_dir/source_file.txt
This is a source file
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ tree
.
├── destination_dir
└── source_dir
    └── source_file.txt

2 directories, 1 file
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ cp source_dir/source_file.txt destination_dir/.
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$ tree
.
├── destination_dir
│   └── source_file.txt
└── source_dir
    └── source_file.txt

2 directories, 2 files
ubuntu@staging-docker:~/copyfile$
```

[image]

Comment: This is a *very elaborate and wordy* way of saying `copy -r source dest`, without ever addressing the issue the OP is facing. Using a shell script to encapsulate the same command won't change the outcome.

Comment: I agree with you but is there any error in my answer. I wrote so many wordy answers so that the problem that I had faced during my initial period was not faced by anyone else.